# Java application in RDP window deploys to host PC

Tags: windows, java, remote-desktop, rdp

I am working with a web application that deploys java components to the client desktop. Those java apps then run on the client desktop to perform various functions. When using this web application inside a remote desktop session at a client it is deploying the java apps to the host PC rather than to the remote desktop machine.

At all my other clients the java apps correctly deploy to the RDP machine, so it must be an issue with this client's specific RDP setup. I know there are various config options with RDP that allow copy paste (or not) between the host PC and RDP window. But I dont know enough about configuration of RDP to understand what might be causing this problem behaviour.

Is anyone able to suggest what aspect of the RDP config might be causing this isssue?

Comment: The RDP server is the host. The end user computer is the client. Where is it being deployed? To the host or to the client?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the terminology was the other way around. It should be deployed inside the host, but is deployed onto the client.